# How to keep the Bootstrap 4.5 accordion according at the top of the page even when it is full of items?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem and cannot find a way to solve it.

I am using the Bootstrap 4.5 accordion and in some of the cards, I have a lot of items(images).
The problem comes when you open a large collapse and open the next one, because the first collapse is so large, the next collapse closes the first one which seems like sending the user at the bottom of the accordion.

I would like to keep the user "view" always centered on the collapse that is being open. Any idea how to do this with Vanilla Javascript please?

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
      images
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
      images
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
      images
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you